# How to infer type for arguments for function?

Tags: typescript

I have a type declaration like this to exclude the return union type:

```js
export type ExcludeReturnType<T extends (...args: any[]) => any, R> = (...args: any) => Exclude<ReturnType<T>, R>

type Orig = (a: number) => string | void
type Result = ExcludeReturnType<Orig, void> // (...args: any[]) => string
type Expected = (a: number) => string
```

But right now it will just turn all parameters into `any[]`. How can I preserve the type of the original function?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=5&ssc=38&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCiIDGAbArgE2ACVgZcoA7AFWWAB4q5QZgL8BnOACgDo+BDKAHN2ALjj8KiANoBdAJRwAvAD4JUgDRwiapdz49BI8ZMSLV6LHkJ0SZSjRQMVWnQCg3SFHADyUAJZCytz84hS4ALYARsBQ5mrsMAEUQQA+cABuEP74nrTawOy42PB6GDgExKTk1LR0foFaWTlqAPSt+gLCYuoyCsoJSf4ped4YKJgs+MFcoXDh0bHxcInJQkA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Parameters` utility type:

```
export type ExcludeReturnType<T extends (...args: any[]) => any, R> = 
  (...args: Parameters<T>) => Exclude<ReturnType<T>, R>
```

```
type Orig = (a: number, b: string) => string | void
type Result = ExcludeReturnType<Orig, void> 
// type Result = (a: number, b: string) => string
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=5&ssc=50&pln=3&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCiIDGAbArgE2ACVgZcoA7AFWWAB4q5QZgL8BnOACgDo%20BDKAHN2ALjj8KiANoBdAJRwAvAD4JUgDRwiapdz49BI8QAVB-ALalgUdgxWLV6LHkJ0SZSjRT2tOgFD%20SChwAPJQAJZCytz84hS4FgBGNlpJ4uwwkRRCjmqZ2dEAPnAAbhAR%20EG02sDsuNjwehg4BMSk5NS0dOFRWuWVav4A9MMINST1jTFccXAJyalw6XAFETl5q1nrQkA)